# How to move UITextFeild with keyboard in order to avoid blocking [SWIFT 5+ ]

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I know that there are several questions on this topic, but i have not been able to find any on [SWIFT 5.0] or more, and would really appreciate your help.

I have a UITextFeild at the bottom of the screen which gets hidden every time the user clicks on it. Is there a recent method on which i can solve this hiding issue, by either the textFeild following the keyboard to the top or a sample field appearing on top of the keyboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Swift 4.0 code will most likely still work. Swift changes these days are much minor. Or which issues have you encountered with Swift 4 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

First, add these two lines of code in your controller viewDidLoad() method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Second, add these two methods inside your controller:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  
    if yourTextfield.isEditing == true
    {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 64
    }
}
```

Enjoy :).

Comment: Better to add the keyboard height to the additional safe area insets

Comment: Btw no need to cast to NSValue. Just cast to CGRect

Comment: What is 64? Don’t hard code values. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Comment: Btw `== true` is redundant

Answer (score 1):

If you use AutoLayout you may try `Keyboard` and `KeyboardLayoutGuide` from my collection of handy Swift extensions and classes called [SwiftToolkit](https://github.com/VasilievMB/SwiftToolkit/tree/master/Sources/UIKit)

Add this code to your controller `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
let keyboardGuide = KeyboardLayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(keyboardGuide)

/** 
    Your textField vertical position constraint 
    must have lower priority than this constraint
*/
keyboardGuide.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

When the keyboard appears it will push your UITextField up like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried using your extensions but Keyboard is throwing errors. Cannot find type 'NotificationObserver' in scope